# How to convert a matrix looking dataframe with row and column labels to a regular pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matrix

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like the matrix below with row and column labels:

```
data=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,3],[2,1,4],[2,3,0.8]]),columns=['d','e','f'],index=['a','b','c'])
```

[image]

I would like to convert it to a proper dataframe which looks like this:

```
output=pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,1,0.8]]),columns=['values'],index=['a-d','a-e','b-e','c-f'])
```

[image]

I tried using pd.melt but it just converts the column labels to row labels without merging them with the existing row labels. Is there a function or a way to achieve my goal in python?

Comment: please add your data as text don't use images

Comment: can you explain some of the logic, where is A-F ?  - IIUC you need `data.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index')`

Comment: i was filtering out the values that were higher than 1  but that is easy enough to do with the df below. thanks very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `melt` and `str.cat`

```
s = data.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index').sort_values('index')
s['index'] = s['index'].str.cat(s['variable'],sep='-')
s = s.drop('variable',axis=1)

print(s)

  index  value
0   a-d    1.0
3   a-e    1.0
6   a-f    3.0
1   b-d    2.0
4   b-e    1.0
7   b-f    4.0
2   c-d    2.0
5   c-e    3.0
8   c-f    0.8
```

## Edit

Cosider this simpler solution as proposed by our resident genius [anky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9840637/anky) using `.pop` in conjunction with `str.cat`

```
s = data.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index').sort_values('index')
s['index'] = s['index'].str.cat(s.pop('variable'),sep='-') 

print(s)

  index  value
0   a-d    1.0
3   a-e    1.0
6   a-f    3.0
1   b-d    2.0
4   b-e    1.0
7   b-f    4.0
2   c-d    2.0
5   c-e    3.0
8   c-f    0.8
```

Answer (score 3):

Start with yourr dataframe:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([[1, 1, 3], [2, 1, 4], [2, 3, 0.8]]),
    columns=["d", "e", "f"],
    index=["a", "b", "c"],
)
print(data)
      d     e     f
a 1.000 1.000 3.000
b 2.000 1.000 4.000
c 2.000 3.000 0.800
```

Use [pandas stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to move the column headers to a multi index.

```
df = data.stack()
print(df)
a  d   1.000
   e   1.000
   f   3.000
b  d   2.000
   e   1.000
   f   4.000
c  d   2.000
   e   3.000
   f   0.800
dtype: float64
```

Use list comprehension to combime the two indices.

```
[x[0] + "-" + x[1] for x in df.index]
print
['a-d', 'a-e', 'a-f', 'b-d', 'b-e', 'b-f', 'c-d', 'c-e', 'c-f']
```

Set the index to the list above.

```
df.index = [x[0] + "-" + x[1] for x in df.index]
print(df)
a-d   1.000
a-e   1.000
a-f   3.000
b-d   2.000
b-e   1.000
b-f   4.000
c-d   2.000
c-e   3.000
c-f   0.800
```